# React Native Update Component State onPress Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

My application is based on expo & i am using redux for state handling. I am having a issue, i want to update the state of component onpress of another component. As you can see in below code, I have two components ItemGenerator & LoadCounter. ItemGenerator generates a list of item which are press able. And LoadCounter just returns the counter value by printing it in Text View. Issue is that when i press the list it updates the counter value in log but LoadCounter state remains the same. But if i reopens the screen again it updates the counter state in LoadCounter. I want to update the state of LoadCounter on press. Kindly guide me to resolve this issue:

List.js

```
 class List extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <View>
                <ItemGenerator />
                <LoadCounter counter={this.props.counter}/>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        counter: state.counter.counter
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        increaseCounter: () => dispatch({ type: 'INCREASE_COUNTER' }),
        decreaseCounter: () => dispatch({ type: 'DECREASE_COUNTER' }),
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(List);
```

ItemGenerator.js

```
 class ItemGenerator extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <ScrollView>
                {
                    this.state.data.map((item, index) => {
                        return(<ItemList navigate={this.props.navigate} data={item} key={index}/>)
                    })
                }
            </ScrollView>
        )
    }

}
```

ItemList.js

```
class ItemList extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <View>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.increaseCounter()}>
                    <Card containerStyle={{margin: 0}}>
                        <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection:'row', height:70, alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'space-between'}}>
                            <View style={{flexDirection:'row', alignItems:'center', width:'55%'}}>
                                <View style={{flexDirection:'column', marginLeft:10}}>
                                    <Text style={{...}}>{this.props.data.name}</Text>
                                </View>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </Card>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        increaseCounter: () => dispatch({ type: 'INCREASE_COUNTER' }),
        decreaseCounter: () => dispatch({ type: 'DECREASE_COUNTER' }),
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ItemList);
```

counterReducer.js

```
const initialState = {
    counter: 1
}
const counterReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'INCREASE_COUNTER':
            return { counter: state.counter + 1 }
        case 'DECREASE_COUNTER':
            return { counter: state.counter - 1 }
    }
    return state
}

export default counterReducer;
```

LoadCounter.js

```
class LoadCounter extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <View>
                <Text>{this.props.counter}</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey. Can you also show the `LoadCounter` and the reducer as well?

Comment: I update the question & also shared LoadCounter + counterReducer

Comment: Please check your `connect` mappings.

Comment: I shared my all code above? Mapping is fine. Only issue is that counter state don't update on press

Comment: in `ItemList.js` you did not connect your `mapDispatchToProps `, same in `List.js`